# php filter_var FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH

Tags: php, sanitize, filter-var

I have the fallowing testcase for the php function function_var():

```php
<?php
$inputvalue = "Ž"; //NUM = 142 on the ASCII extended list

$sanitized = filter_var($inputvalue, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH);

echo 'The sanitized output: '.$sanitized."\n"; // --> & #197;& #189; (Å ½)
?>
```

If you run the above snippet the output is not what I expect to be returned. The Ž is number 142 in the ASCII extended list (see: ascii-code[dot]com). So what I expect to get back is the '& #142;' (string, without the space).

I had [help](http://gathering.tweakers.net/forum/list_message/39702978) finding out what is going wrong I just dont know how to solve it yet.

If you convert 'Ž' to Hex UTF-8 bytes you get: C5 BD. These hex bytes correspond with the ISO-8859 hex values: Å ½(see: http://cs.stanford.edu/~miles/iso8859.html). These 2 characters then get decoded by filter_var to '& #197;& #189;'.

See this onlineconverter!!!: http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=%C5%BD&mode=char

So basically what happens: UTF-8 bytes are used to translate them as Latin-1 characters bytes. The converter page says the fallowing: "UTF-8 bytes as Latin-1 characters" is what you typically see when you display a UTF-8 file with a terminal or editor that only knows about 8-bit characters.

I dont think my editor is the problem. I am using a Mac with Coda 2 (UTF-8 as default). The test has also been tested on a html5 page with meta character set to utf-8. Furthermore I am using a defaut XAMPP localhost server. With Firebug in Firefox I also checked if the file was served as UTF-8 (it is).

Anyone got a idea how I can solve this encoding problem?

Comment: Is `$inputvalue` hard-coded into the script or does it come from user input or a database?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't `htmlspecialchars()` be enough?

Comment: @pateman: no, htmlspecialchars only does `<>"'&`, e.g. the html metacharacters. think of it as the html equivalent of mysql_real_escape_string(). htmlentities() is the more generic "encode anything".

Comment: Marc B, right - I tend to confuse these two. Still, `htmlentities()` should work in this case, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, it originally came from a html input, but both would have the same result. 
And filter_far can be used to strip/encode low or high ASCII characters. It can also be used to validate input such as email, int, boolean's...

Answer (score 0):

I am gona drop this cause I am not finding any solution. The email() function is also not safe and I am gona use either phpmailer or swiftmailer (and I am leaning towards the latter).